# MySQL convert a column into dat format

Tags: mysql, date, date-format

The column type is bigint and the values are

20211123
20220125

How can I change it to date:

2021-11-23
2022-01-25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string functions to extract the characters, they'll automatically convert the number to a string.

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', LEFT(colname, 4), SUBSTR(colname, 5, 2), RIGHT(colname, 2)) 
            AS DATE) AS date
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: But won't it be a string/char type and not the date format. I need it as a date format so that I can perform further operations such as DATEDIFF with another column in the table

Comment: You said you wanted a date format, not a date, I thought you wanted a string.

Comment: All the date functions will work with this string, they'll automatically convert it to a date.